# How do I run edge on login in Group policy &/Or login script

Tags: authentication, vbscript, microsoft-edge, group-policy

I am trying to run edge on all client machines when they log in. This is easily done with IE as you just set iexplore.exe in the Startup section of Group Policy but not having much luck with Edge.

I have tried creating a .bat / .cmd and trying to call it

Code:

```
@echo off
start microsoft-edge:https://google.ie/
```

I know the above works as Edge opens up when i double click the cmd/bat

I am trying to call this from within a login.vbs script but am having no joy, any ideas? or alternatively if anyone has been able to get this working in Group policy? Thanks.

VBS Code:

```
    Function Edge()
    dim shell
    set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
    shell.run "\\ipbdc3\SYSVOL\ipbdomain.local\scripts\edge.cmd"
    set shell=nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Most basic of questions first - Is that your whole `vbscript`?  As if it is, you haven't actually called the function `Edge()` in it.  Also, rather than call the `cmd` file, have you considered using `.Run` to just start the application directly?

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the input, I thought the shell.run command would have looked after this. Im not very familiar with vbscript, can you tell me how I would call this function then? And yes I agree using the Run command would probably better as that way we wont see a dos box popping up prior to Edge opening. Could you provide some sample code on this? I've played around and cant seem to get it to work. Many thanks,David

Comment: You've declared the function `Edge()` in the `vbscript`, but you would need to have the script call the function in order to execute the code inside it.  If all you have is the function in your vbscript, then you can either add the statement `Edge()` somewhere after the function declaration, or just remove the `Function Edge()` and `End Function` lines and let the vbscript execute the steps directly rather than have them in a function...

Comment: All working now thanks Dave